# React phaser Reinitialize problem because of grid-engine plugin

Tags: reactjs, phaser-framework

I use "phaser", 'ion-phaser' and a phaser plugin 'grid-engine' for integrate a phaser game to react.
I can initialize the game successfully, then destroy it without an error. But when I try to reinitialize it İt give 2 errors

```
Scene Plugin key in use: GridEngine
```

and

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')
at Scene.create (isometric.js:93:1)
at SceneManager.create (phaser.js:84684:1)
at SceneManager.loadComplete (phaser.js:84615:1)
at LoaderPlugin.emit (phaser.js:1671:1)
at LoaderPlugin.loadComplete (phaser.js:165337:1)
at LoaderPlugin.fileProcessComplete (phaser.js:165311:1)
at SpriteSheetFile.onProcessComplete (phaser.js:4290:1)
at data.onload (phaser.js:16548:1)
```

second error at this line

```
this.gridEngine.create(cloudCityTilemap, gridEngineConfig);
```

Additionally when I try a phaser game without plugins like grid engine, there is not an error.
I search and I think I must remove grid-engine plugin when destroy game but I could not find how.
My question is

> How to destroy a phaser game with included plugins and restart it?

this is code sample

```
          const game = {
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        scene: {
          preload,
          create,
          update,
        },
        plugins: {
          scene: [
            {
              key: 'GridEngine',
              plugin: GridEngine,
              mapping: 'gridEngine'
            },
          ],
        },
      }
  const gameRef = useRef(null)
  const [initialize, setInitialize] = useState(false)
  const destroy = () => {
    if (gameRef.current) {
      gameRef.current.destroy()
    }
    setInitialize(false)
  }
  return (
    <>
      <IonPhaser game={game}  ref={gameRef} initialize={initialize} />
      <button onClick={()=>setInitialize(true)}>Initialize</button>
      <button onClick={destroy}>Destroy</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

Finally I want to change different games or levels at the same page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not 100% sure, if this will solve all your problems, but

```
<button onClick={setInitialize(true)}>
```

is not correct, you should not call the function, you should only pass it.
Try replacing that line with

```
<button onClick={ () => setInitialize(true)}>
```

For Details, checkout this [article / documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) for details.

**Update: *How to get the game object***

to get the Phaser Game object you would have to use `getInstance` ([link to ion-phaser documentation](https://github.com/proyecto26/ion-phaser/blob/develop/src/components/ion-phaser/readme.md)) and to remove the Plugin you would have to do something like this:

```
this.gameRef.current.getInstance()
    .then(game => game.plugins.removeScenePlugin("GridEngine"))
```

Comment: thanks for answer, You are right, it is my mistake when I cut my codes I wrong but original codes true. I want to learn how can I change "game" config without refresh page and so I have to improve "destroy" function.
in game config I add this line for remove plugin
this.sys.game.plugins.removeScenePlugin("GridEngine"); but from react I don't know how can I reach "this"

Comment: @SinanA well if you only want the `this.sys.game.plugins` (aka `Phaser.Plugins.PluginManager`), you could direct access it from the `game` object I assume `gameRef.plugins.removeScenePlugin("GridEngine")`. [link to Phaser.Game Docs](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Game.html#plugins__anchor). but I know littel reactjs.

Comment: thanks again, but I try a lot of versions like gameRef.current.game.plugins.removeScenePlugin("GridEngine"), gameRef.plugins..., gameRef.plugins.game... etc. it gives error "Uncaught TypeError: foo.bar..removeScenePlugin is not a function" every time. so I can not reach this function outside phaser config

Comment: @SinanA I updated my answer with the solution to get the Phaser Game Object, I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer is right for me